# Ruby: Write to stdin and read from stdout?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a ruby program that is supposed to execute another program, pass values to it via stdin, read the response from its stdout, and then print the response.  This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('./MyProgram')

stdin.puts "hello world!"

output = stdout.read
errors = stderr.read

stdin.close
stdout.close
stderr.close

puts "Output:"
puts "-------"
puts output
puts "\nErrors:"
puts "-------"
puts errors
```

I am definitely doing something wrong here - when I run this it seems to be waiting for me to enter text.  I don't want to be prompted for anything - I want to start `./MyProgram`, pass in `"hello world!"`, get back the response, and print the response on the screen.  How do I do this?

**EDIT**

Just in case it matters, `MyProgram` is basically a program that keeps running until EOF, reading in and printing out stuff.

Comment: What code `./MyProgram` contains ?

Comment: Can you do just `p Open3.popen3('./MyProgram')` ?

Comment: The problem is usually that the child program wants to read its STDIN completely, before trying to process what it read and outputting the results. That means you have to close your STDIN handle, which gets passed to the child, which then knows its OK to finish its processing. It's akin to the parent code reading a file to its end before finishing its processing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try closing stdin before reading the output. Here's an example:

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3("./MyProgram") do |i, o, e, t|
  i.write "Hello World!"
  i.close
  puts o.read
end
```

Here's a more succint way of writing it using [**`Open3::capture3`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3): (beware, untested!)

```
o, e, s= Open3.capture3("./MyProgram", stdin_data: "Hello World!")
puts o
```

Answer (score 0):

a brief working way:

```rb
require 'open3'

out, err, status = Open3.capture3("./parser", stdin_data: "hello world")

out # string with standard output
err # string with error output
status.success? # true/false
status.exitstatus # 0 / 1 / ...
```

for more examples including sending binary input: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3